# How to avoid VHD detaching on network outage

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

I have VHD hosted in AWS attached to local servers as a backup destination. Problem is every 3-4 days network connectivity to the host drop intermittently and the VHD is detached, it needs to be manually re-attached.

Is there any way the VHD can be automatically re-attached when this happen?

Comment: Is the backup job running all the time?  If not can you have your backup job attach the VHD on demand, and then disconnect when the job is complete?  Should be pretty easy to attach VHD as needed with powershell.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea except atm I'm using Windows Server Backup. I'll consider this approach

Comment: I believe Windows Server Backup is triggered by a Scheduled Task by default.  I think it would be relatively easy to remove the scheduled task, and instead schedule a script that attached the VHD, ran the backup job using wbadmin, verified it completed, and the disconnects.